# Where can I ask questions about Valgrind, if anywhere?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

[Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) is a tool that watches the execution of a program and detects problems like uninitialised data leading to undefined behavior, memory leaks, etc.

Is there a good place in Stack Exchange to ask about the output that this tool produces? Some of the things I see I don't understand.

A meta-meta question would be: Where can I ask about where to ask about specific kinds of topics? I.e., where is it best to ask questions like this?

I could continue with the metas, but I think this is meta enough.

Comment: How about valgrind's [own support mechanisms](https://valgrind.org/support/mailing_lists.html)?

Comment: @RobertLongson no voting system, boring. ;-)

Comment: Is stackoverflow not a good place?

Comment: Stack Overflow has a [Valgrind tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valgrind) with 3,857 questions. It may not even be necessary to ask a question. The answer may already be in there.

Comment: Samples: *[Understanding the Valgrind output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479684/)*, *[Understanding Valgrind output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748968/)*, and *[Understanding Valgrind's output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308927/)* (though the titles may be too unspecific)

Comment: @wha7ever [Not always, no](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow)